# Using Pages to handle calls for custom post types

Tags: pages, templates

I have created a page on which I would like to run queries exlusively for one custom post type in the same way I'm using Category.php, Author.php and index.php to run queries for regular posts.  I can't seem to get anything to appear when I edit the page that is associated with the template I've created for this page, so I've edited the actual page template itself.  This may or may not be related to the fact that I can't get this page to behave like index.php does, i.e. providing a running list of posts until someone does a more refined search such as by Category.

I'm stumped - how can I get a page template to work just like index.php does, but for the custom post type only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the template file `archive-{posttype}.php` to output an archive index of your Custom Post Type, and the template file `single-{posttype}.php` to output a single Custom Post.

Refer to the [Codex entry for Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display).

Comment: Thanks, Chip.  But I've got an unresolved issue with the system not reading my archive-{posttype}.php.  It does read my single-{posttype}.php, however.  It is registered appropriately, etc.  I have to develop a workaround, so do you know if there's a way to have a page -running off of its own template (and I edited the template directly) for a custom post type, to act as index.php does (as the default template) for regular posts?

Comment: What version of WordPress are you using? IIRC, `archive-{posttype}.php` [only works in WordPress 3.1+](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Template_Files).

Comment: I'm using 3.1.3

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the system is "not reading" your "archive-{posttype}.php template file? Can you update your question to describe what's happening/not happening as you expect? What is your custom post type named (perhaps post the entire registration code)? What is your archive-{posttype}.php template file named? Also: if you put `<?php post_type_archive_title(); ?>` in your archive template file, does the Custom Post Type Title output?

Comment: I posted the custom post type registration code on my original question.  The category.php template will call the custom post type business_sold, but archive-business_sold.php will not and I need to format what information will post separately.  I also need to have the queries run on a separate page from the same query from regular posts.  WP is running in a sub directory of my primary HTML site and I am using index.php as the 'home page' for my regular posts.  I need to use a different page with a different URL on which to run my queries for my custom post type.

Comment: Chip:  No, the custom post type title does not output with:  `<?php post_type_archive_title(); ?>`

Comment: Okay, then I suspect you're doing something wrong with your Custom Post Type, or with your `archive-business_sold.php` template file.

Comment: It doesn't output when I add that code to the page template that I've created, but it would output when anyone would do a category search (separate categories from regular post categories).  I could get a running list of all of them because I assigned all of them to a default category of All.  I had added the following code to functions.php for that to happen:

Comment: Sorry, here's the code:  `function cpt_Search_category_Filter($query) {
    $post_type = array('post','business_sold');
    if ($query->is_search || $query->is_category) {
        $query->set('post_type', $post_type);    
      };    
      return $query;
};`

Comment: You say "page template". Are you referring to a *static Page template*, or to your `archive-business_sold.php` template file?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to a static page template that I've named business_sold.php.  Would I be able to stop going down this path and try (again!) to fix archive-business_sold.php?  Would the latter serve as a destination URL where all queries of the custom post type 'Businesses Sold' could happen?

Comment: "*Would the latter serve as a destination URL where all queries of the custom post type 'Businesses Sold' could happen?*" - **YES!** That is the purpose of the `archive-{posttype}.php` template file: to serve as the template file for rendering the *archive index* of Posts of the Custom Post Type. If you have a *static Page* of the same name, I honestly don't know how WordPress would handle that.

Comment: Thank you - sorry that I'm so ignorant about this.  Do you have any ideas on what could be wrong with my file?  It appears that the post type is registered correctly - correct? It has an archive, among other things. I had simply copied my archive.php file and renamed it to archive-business_sold.php.  Do I need anything more than that?

Comment: Here is my code for archive-business_sold.php:

Comment: The first thing to try is to remove your custom archive template completely, and let WordPress fall back to the default ( `archive.php` ), just to see what is output. (Also, I would rename the *slug* of any *static Page* that is the same as your Custom Post Type name, i.e. `business_sold`.) What is your permalink structure, and what do you see when you go to `www.example.com/business_sold/`?

Comment: I'm going to get rid of the static page since it won't work anyway - thank you for that.  I had tried removing the CPT archive file and letting it default to archive.php and that didn't work - maybe that's the file that's coded incorrectly. I will try all of that again.  `www.oibmn.com/listings/business_sold` is 'not found'/invalid.  The permalink structure is `%category%/%slug%`.

Comment: What is `listings`?

Comment: Thank you for checking.  Listings is the sub directory in which WP is housed.  My site is primarily HTML.

Comment: `www.oibmn.com/listings/business_sold` is now working.  I'm making progress with your help!  Now I just have to get the post title to appear and a separate menu widget to appear only there and I think it's working!